# Fedora 19 Eclipse/NetBeans do not recognize Samsung Galaxy Note phone

Tags: fedora, android, eclipse

I cannot force Eclipse/Netbeans under Fedora 19 to recognize my Samsung Galaxy Note phone and therefore I cannot deploy app neither run it neither debug it. Can someone explain me what do I have to do so IDEs will recognize my phone? From terminal, if I use `lsusb` command, my phone is visible under USB tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there's not amazing mtp (media transport protocol) support in Fedora... yet! Which is a rather popular way for smartphones to talk to your system.

However, there are some people that are having luck, by using [go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs). Which may provide the route for you to automount your device when you plug it in.

My experience here is relative only to the Galaxy Nexus, however, the most reliable route for me (in Fedora) has been to use [ADB, the Android Debugger](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

It's visible with `lsusb` because your system knows how to recognize a USB device, however, what it's lacking are the tools to properly use mtp.

Comment: Yes, of course, but ADB in Fedora also does not detect my phone!